# Get SKProduct price and priceLocale from productIdentifier

Tags: ios, skproduct

Is there a way to get the `SKProduct` and the `price` and `priceLocale` attributes from just knowing the `productIdentifier`?

Comment: You must use `SKProductsRequest`.

Comment: Is it possible to use the `SKProductRequestDelegate` in more than one class? If I have multiple delegates for `productRequest:didReceiveResponse` in my app - how would that work? Also is there a way to return these `SKProduct` attributes so that I can use them?